# Turn ON Anti-Aliasing in WPF (.NET 4.5.2)

Tags: wpf, antialiasing, .net-4.5.2

I know, there are a lot of posts to Anti-Aliasing in WPF. But I have nothing found for my problem.

Most people want to turn OFF Anti-Aliasing in WPF. But I want to turn it ON. I use .NET 4.5.2 and I am drawing `DrawingVisual`s with `RenderOpen`. Inclined lines are drawn "stairs-like", but I want them smooth.

In an older application I used .NET 4 and everything worked fine. Anti-aliasing was turned ON as default.
`RenderOptions.EdgeMode = EdgeMode.Unspecified` doesn't help!

How can I turn ON Anti-Aliasing in .NET 4.5.2 ?

Comment: Maybe Im to far because I've never used it by my self but...check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t6sa8s9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you; but that's the right way for GDI+, not for WPF!

Comment: I have found the reason. In a container far up the visual tree RenderOptions are set to EdgeMode.Aliased. And though i set RenderOptions in my drawing Canvas explicit to EdgeMode.Unspecified this seems to be ignored. Is this a bug?

Comment: @ubsch I am having same issue